# How can I use arcgis js in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arcgis

There are several example in [docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-frameworks-vue/) of arcgis, but I can't use it properly. When I import Map from arcgis like shown as in that [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/install-and-set-up/):

`import Map from '@arcgis/Map'`

It gives error in browser which not found ersi like that [image]

Why it tries to download files from assets?

Comment: The docs says: `import Map from "@arcgis/core/Map";`

Comment: @dhruwlalan thanks, I have fixed the issue by manually copying all assets as in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ArcGIS JS API with ES modules, you need to copy the `@arcgis/core/assets` to the build directory.

This can be done using the `ncp` npm module and setup npm scripts like such.

```
// package.json
{
    "script": {
        "start": "npm run copy && react-scripts start",
        "build": "npm run copy && react-scripts build",
        "copy": "ncp ./node_modules/@arcgis/core/assets ./public/assets"
    }
}
```

It is the way the ArcGIS JS API documentation lists how to do it. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/es-modules/

Alternatively if you use Webpack, you can use the `copy-webpack-plugin` to accomplish it as well. https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin then in your `webpack.config.js`

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './node_modules/@arcgis/core/assets', to: './public/assets' },
    ]
  ],
```